# Unusual Crop/GeneralPath behaviour in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I created a minor crop image app which crops the set image in a closed free path defined by the user (closed by joining the starting and ending point). This app is depicting unusual behavior when cropping in different path directions (clockwise and anticlockwise). Can anyone explain why is this happening and how to rectify this problem?

The following is the code:-

My own defined GeneralPath class

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.charts.util.ColorUtil;
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Stroke;

public class GeneralPath extends Component{

    com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath generalPath;
    Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
    int firstPointX = 0, firstpointY = 0;
    MyApplication myApplication;

    public GeneralPath(MyApplication application) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        generalPath = new com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath();
        stroke.setLineWidth(Math.max(1, Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true)/2));
        getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
        getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(200);
        myApplication = application;
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paint(g);
        paintDrawing(g);
    }
    private void paintDrawing(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(ColorUtil.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        boolean oldAA = g.isAntiAliased();
        g.setAntiAliased(true);
        g.drawShape(generalPath, stroke);
        g.setAntiAliased(oldAA);
    }
    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int a, int b) {
        firstPointX = a;
        firstpointY = b;
        generalPath.moveTo(x(a), y(b));
    }
    @Override
    public void pointerDragged(int a, int b) {
        generalPath.lineTo(x(a), y(b));
    }
    @Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        generalPath.lineTo(x(firstPointX), y(firstpointY));
        myApplication.clip();
    }
    public int x(int x)
    {
        return x-getParent().getAbsoluteX();
    }
    public int y(int y)
    {
        return y - getParent().getAbsoluteY();
    }
    public com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath getPath()
    {
        return generalPath;
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java (main class)

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.Stroke;
import com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.util.UITimer;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    Form hi;
    com.mycompany.myapp.GeneralPath gp;
    Image finalDuke;


    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
//        Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
//        final Label apple = new Label(theme.getImage("apple-icon.png")); 
//        final Label android = new Label(theme.getImage("android-icon.png")); 
//        final Label windows = new Label(theme.getImage("windows-icon.png")); 
//        Button getStarted = new Button("Let's Get Started!");
//        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(getStarted, FontImage.MATERIAL_LINK);
//        getStarted.setUIID("GetStarted");
//        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, 
//                LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
//                        BoxLayout.encloseY(
//                                new Label(theme.getImage("duke-no-logos.png")),
//                                getStarted
//                        ),
//                        FlowLayout.encloseRightMiddle(apple)
//                    )
//        );
//        
//        getStarted.addActionListener((e) -> {
//            Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.codenameone.com/developers.html");
//        });
//        
//        new UITimer(() -> {
//            if(apple.getParent() != null) {
//                apple.getParent().replace(apple, android, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
//            } else {
//                if(android.getParent() != null) {
//                    android.getParent().replace(android, windows, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
//                } else {
//                    windows.getParent().replace(windows, apple, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
//                }                
//            }
//        }).schedule(2200, true, hi);

        Image duke = null;
        try {
            // duke.png is just the default Codename One icon copied into place
            duke = theme.getImage("promo_5.png");
        } catch(Exception err) {
            Log.e(err);
        }
        finalDuke = duke;

        hi = new Form("Shape Clip", new BorderLayout());

        // We create a 50 x 100 shape, this is arbitrary since we can scale it easily
//        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
//       path.moveTo(20,0);
//        path.lineTo(30, 0);
//       path.lineTo(30, 100);
//        path.lineTo(20, 100);
//        path.lineTo(20, 15);
//        path.lineTo(5, 40);
//        path.lineTo(5, 25);
//        path.lineTo(20,0);

        gp = new com.mycompany.myapp.GeneralPath(this);
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,gp);
        hi.getLayeredPane().add(finalDuke);



        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
    public void clip()
    {
        Stroke stroke = new Stroke(0.5f, Stroke.CAP_ROUND, Stroke.JOIN_ROUND, 4);
//        hi.getContentPane().getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter((Graphics g, Rectangle rect) -> {
//            g.setColor(0xff0000);
//            float widthRatio = ((float)rect.getWidth()) / 50f;
//            float heightRatio = ((float)rect.getHeight()) / 100f;
//            g.scale(widthRatio, heightRatio);
//            g.translate((int)(((float)rect.getX()) / widthRatio), (int)(((float)rect.getY()) / heightRatio));
//            g.setClip(gp.getPath());
//            g.setAntiAliased(true);
//            g.drawImage(finalDuke, 0, 0, 50, 100);
//            g.setClip(gp.getPath().getBounds());
//            g.drawShape(gp.getPath(), stroke);
//            g.translate(-(int)(((float)rect.getX()) / widthRatio), -(int)(((float)rect.getY()) / heightRatio));
//            g.resetAffine();
 //       });

        hi.getContentPane().getAllStyles().setBgPainter((Graphics g, Rectangle rect) -> {
            g.drawShape(gp.getPath(), stroke);
            g.setClip(gp.getPath());
            Image image = finalDuke;
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        });

    }
}
```

Please ignore the commented out portions. Thank you

ScreenShots:-

[image]

3 overlapping rectangles don't invert the picture during crop but a triangular shape in the opposite direction of that to the rectangle inversely cuts the previous paths

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Can you provide some illustrative screenshots that would explain how this will look?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog updated a couple of screenshots with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [closePath()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/geom/GeneralPath.html#closePath--) in pointerReleased.  Even the user is *almost* closing the path manually, it might not really be closed.  If you try to use an unclosed shape as a clip shape you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: I join the co-ordinates of the pointer pressed and the pointer released in the pointerReleased() method in GeneralPath class so it is never a unclosed shape

Comment: You don't invoke closePath in the code above, do you mean that you tried that?

Comment: It's hard to understand what's wrong from the images above, both look "correct". Can you explain?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog The problem I encounter is consistency for a pattern. Like if I place two overlapping rectangles over each other, they don't inversely crop the overlapping region. But when I perform the same operation in a shape of a circle's arc with a counter-clockwise direction assuming that the first arc was made clockwise, then the overlapping region is inversely cropped

Comment: For the "overlapping rectangles" case, are you forming said rectangles using `GeneralPath.lineTo()` also using the code above, or using a different mechanism?   The default winding rule for a GeneralPath is NON_ZERO, which will change overlap behaviour depending on direction.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule .  Change it to EVEN_ODD for different results that might be more consistent for you.

Comment: @stevehannah When I say rectangle, I do mean a free hand shape of 4 vertices drawn using the same mechanism as the circular (using the same mechanism stated above). I understand the Even-Odd rule and it does give a more consistent result because it is easy to predict whether the area will be inverse cropped or not. The consistency problem is with the Non-Zero Rule. It should yield consistent results with respect to direction irrespective of the shape of the closed path. Yet it yields different results for a circular arc and free hand drawn rectangle

Comment: The best thing to do in a case like this is to manually code a path to create your clip, so that you have a reproducible test case that can be analyzed and tested against other implementations.  I think it is most likely that it is working correctly, but there is some aspect of the shape that is causing these correct results to differ from what you want - but it is impossible to know without a concrete example.

Comment: @stevehannah How do you suggest I proceed with this testing. Please keep in mind that I'm kind of a noob in CN1 and in programming in general but am willing to put in the effort :)

Comment: Construct a path using code doesn't rely on the user dragging the pointer, and use that for the clip.  Try to recreate the problem.  That way you'll be able to better understand what is going on.